# List LDAP trusted domains with Java

Tags: java, dns, active-directory, adsi

We're migrating from C to Java, and we need to query Active-Dirctory Domain to get the list of trusted domains. Until now, we've done it with ADSI.

And a second question. Is the concept of "trusted domains" only related to Active-Directory Domain, or is it a more general concept related to the LDAP specification itself?

Comment: Generally, you don't want to post 2 questions as 1, but I'm having trouble figuring out what your first question was...

Comment: Is your question still valid ?